# Confusion with weak Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $X$ be an affine algebraic variety of $k^{n}$, $k$ algebraically closed. $I(X)$ the ideal of the polynomials that vanish in $X$, prove that if $I(X)\not = (1)$, then $X$ is not empty.

What is the problem with taking $f\not \in I(X)$ and saying that by definition exists $x\in X$ with $f(x)\not = 0$, in particular exists $x\in X$?

Comment: I don't see any.

Comment: Well in Atiyah this result uses Noether normalization lemma.

Comment: It may depend on the different definitions chosen. But in any case the contraposition of your statement is $X$ empty implies $I(X)=1$ which should be straightforward whichever definition you chose.
Are you sure this is what Atyiah is wanting to prove?

Comment: Yes, is problem 17 of chapter 5...

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know this book. So could you tell me what definitions you have?

Comment: I think you're right. More precisely, my opinion (for what it's worth) is that the Weak Nullstellensatz is not well stated in Exercise 5.17 of Atiyah's and MacDonald's commutative algebra book, and that the correct statement is: if $I\ne(1)$, then $V(I)\ne\varnothing$; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz#Formulation. +1

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/a/73753/461